# Separate data based on latitude and longitude matlab

Tags: matlab, latitude-longitude

I have a set of data that needs to be organised into sections based on where the data was collected. There are 5 sections that the data may fall into, therefore I need to separate the data into these five sections based on their latitude and longitude. How would I go about doing this?

Here is a sample. The first few columns contain information regarding the voyage, the 5th column contains the latitude at which the data was collected, the 6th contains the longitude. The next columns contain information on time of collection and results of the data collection.

> 2 , NaN, 83, NaN, -62.18, -36.59, 1983, 318, 0, 0.1, NaN, 0.28,   6,
>   1.06, 0.66, 0.41, 0.29, 0.26, 0.30, 0.39, 0.49, 0.60, 0.67, 0.68, 0.64,   0.56, 0.45, 0.36, 0.28, 0.22, 0.18, 0.15, 0.13, 0.11, 0.10, 0.09, 0.07

Comment: Some example of data and the expected result would be useful.

Comment: it is difficult to show a sample of the data as it is a 890 by 37 matrix. The first few columns contain information regarding the voyage, the 5th column contains the latitude at which the data was collected, the 6th contains the longitude. The next columns contain information on time of collection and results of the data collection. A simplified example of one row would be:



2 , NaN, 83, NaN, -62.18, -36.59, 1983, 318, 0, 0.1, NaN, 0.28, 6, 1.06, 0.66, 0.41, 0.29, 0.26, 0.30, 0.39, 0.49, 0.60, 0.67, 0.68, 0.64, 0.56, 0.45, 0.36, 0.28, 0.22, 0.18, 0.15, 0.13, 0.11, 0.10, 0.09, 0.07



Thanks,

Comment: How are these Areas defined? Polygons? Min/Max longitude / latitude? Circles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `csvread` as the data is numeric only. And access the lat/lon by standard column indexing.

```
M = csvread(filename);
lat = M(:,5);
lon = M(:,6);
```

Then select the indexes corresponding to your criteria and extract the data

```
% a N x 4 matrix, N lines for the number of groups, and 4 columns for min(lat) max(lat) min(lon) max(lon) 
lat_lon_values = [10 20 50 80;
    20 30 50 80;
    50 70 10 60];

for ind_group = 1:size(lat_lon_values, 1)

    a = lat_lon_values(ind_group, 1); %min(lat)
    b = lat_lon_values(ind_group, 2); %max(lat)
    c = lat_lon_values(ind_group, 3); %min(lon)
    d = lat_lon_values(ind_group, 4); %max(lon)

    %select the indexes based on lat and lon values
    ind_line = M(5,:)>= a & M(5,:)<= b & M(6,:)>= c & M(6,:)<= d;

    %your selected data
    M(ind_line, :)

end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm fairly new to matlab and am unsure as to how column indexing could be used to do this? The file is already a matrix in matlab and doesn't need to be read in the data just needs to be grouped according to where it was collected

Comment: Please see the edit. The solution proposed uses a `for` loop that goes through the criteria and eslect the data

Comment: Thank you, just one last problem. My data is not arranged so that with positive and negative values (depending if east or west, north or south) and therefore the minimum and maximum may go from positive to negative ie the region starts at 160 and runs to -130. How do I account for this problem?

Comment: You can create a second `lat_lon_values` matrix, select row indexes in `ind_line2`,  and then take the union of the two index matrices: `ind_line_union = ind_line | ind_line2`. `|` stands for OR.